# iOS provisioning portal - Configure link missing under the action Section fo configuring APP ID for Push Notification

Tags: iphone, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am trying to create a new provisioning profile to test Push notification. I crated a new APP ID without wildcard. After creating the APP ID I am trying to configure it for push notification. Unfortunately configure button/link is missing in the Action column. It is showing as enabled for the Game center and In App purchase but for Push notification service its showing as configurable with a yellow indicator. Please check the image attached (In the image I am hiding the APP ID description.).[image]

Any clue what I am missing?

Please help Thanks,

Comment: Where is attached image?

Comment: I edited the post. Please check the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I figured out that only **Team Agent** can do the AppID configuration. I was logged in as **Team admin**.